# Python multiprocessing Pool.map uses all cores instead of the specified number

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cpu, cpu-cores, htop

I am using the `multiprocessing` module of Python and more precisely the `Pool` class and its `map` method to run a function (called `evaluate`) in parallel onto a list of Python objects (called `object_list`).

The problem occurs with a computer that has 2CPUs of 20 cores each:

```
>>> import multiprocessing as mp
>>> mp.cpu_count()
40
```

Each run of the function is quite long and also independent, so I chose `multiprocessing` module to run my function on my list instead of doing it in serial with a `for` loop for instance.

So basically I am using the `Pool` class, the `map` method and specifies the `processes` argument to be 8. The syntax is then:

```
# import the module
import multiprocessing as mp

# creating a Pool instance that should run 8 cores
pool = mp.Pool(processes=8)

# running my evaluations in parallel using Pool.map
pool.map(evaluate, object_list)
```

Unfortunately, my code is too long, and I have not been able to provide a minimum working example. All I can do is describe what syntax I use (like above). So here is my problem.

I run my script on 2 computers. The first one is composed of a CPU of 12 cores. The second one is composed of 2 CPUs of 20 cores each.

1. When I run my script on the first computer, on 8 cores (`processes=8`), the terminal command `htop` shows, as expected, 8 lines for my script (called `EA_launch.py`):
   [image: multiprocessing running as expected]
2. Now, for the second computer, all cores (40) are running, even if it is the exact same script, and only 8 cores are specified. As we can see, 8 processes are written in white, and the rest are in green. I don't really understand the green ones.

[image]

Note that in the screenshot above, the lines with green `python EA_launch.py` keeps going over 200 lines. The `htop` commands shows also that all 40 cores are running (instead of 8). The evaluation is incredibly slowed. I understand that running a code in parallel does not automatically mean better performances. But in my case, with the first computer, running in parallel makes the code much faster (as expected), but with the second computer, this "strange" behavior with the cores make it incredibly slower.

Can anyone enlighten me on that matter ? It seems, the fact that the second computer has 2 CPUs messes with `multiprocessing` module.

Comment: I assume `processes=4` on the 8-core machine also uses all the cores there, and `processes=8` only happened to work because it's the same number as the core count?

Comment: Oups I may have not been really clear: my first computer is composed of 1 CPU of 12 cores. So running with `processes=n` results in `n` processes appearing in the `htop`. With `n=4` or `n=8` there is no problem with the first computer, it behaves as expected.

The problem lies with the second computer (2CPUs of 20 cores each), where, `processes=n` with `n` > 1.

Comment: Ok, so the same program works differently on different computers.  What versions of things do you have on each system?  Python version, and any separate packages.

Comment: Thank, you are right, I should enquire on that, since it is the only thing that differs the two cases. I don't know yet, I will ask my colleagues.

Comment: Python 3.11.4 and 2 x Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6230 => 2 x 20 CPUs for the second computer

Comment: This is definitely buggy behavior.. messing around with `Pool._pool` could cause this, but I would maybe start with reinstalling python real quick. If you can't do that easily, I would at least go copy the latest python source for multiprocessing/pool.py

Comment: Note that some CPU usage > 100%. Is `evaluate` a single thread routine?